# Fetch random records which definitely contains a given set of records, using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, in-subquery

I want to use a query just like this; but I know it's not true usage.

In total I need 15 category ids (4,5,6,9,10 and random 10 ids other than the specified)

Tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
WHERE id IN (CONCAT('4,5,6,9,10', SELECT id from categories WHERE id NOT IN(4,5,6,9,10) ORDER BY RAND())) 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Could you help me to edit this one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is not working?

Comment: I want to get categories that's id's 4,5,6,9,10 and some 10 id from subquery order by rand.

Comment: In total you need 15 ids (4,5,6,9,10 and rand 10 ids other than the specified). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct Vamsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix constants and subqueries in an `in` clause.  The following fixes the syntax errors, but doesn't actually solve the problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
WHERE id IN (4,5,6,9,10) or
      id IN (SELECT id from categories WHERE id NOT IN (4,5,6,9,10) ORDER BY RAND()
            ) 
LIMIT 0,15;
```

You can do what you want this way:

```
select *
from categories
order by (id in (4, 5, 6, 9, 10)) desc,
      rand()
limit 15;
```

This will return 10 rows, 5 of which are your desired ids and the rest of which are randomly chosen.  (This assumes that `id` is unique in the `categories` table.)

Comment: Hi, I need the two result so I can't use OR between them.

In total I need 15 ids (4,5,6,9,10 and rand 10 ids other than the specified).

Comment: @vural . . . The first version fixes your syntax errors.  The second does what I think you want.

Comment: Gordon; In total I need 15 ids (4,5,6,9,10 and rand 10 ids other than the specified).

Comment: @vural increase the limit to 15.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess the first one is not what OP is after. The second one is his requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your helps my friends. The second query that Gordon shared is working.

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM categories 
   WHERE id IN (4,5,6,9,10)
   or id in(
   SELECT id from categories WHERE id NOT IN(4,5,6,9,10) ORDER BY RAND()
           )
   LIMIT 0,10
```